# C# Get All WindowsApps

Tags: c#, windows, process

Is there a possible way to retrieve all installed WindowsApps?
I need a list of all application executables to execute them with `Process.start()` if i need to.

I know that you can get the content of `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`, but this folder does not contain installed Microsoft Store applications or pre-installed software like `Calculator`, `Groove-Music`, etc.

Comment: Well that's not going to work, try the registry key SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, FAIR WARNING : you should do your own due diligence here, your own research, learn the dangers of playing around in the registry, and <insert other warnings i couldn't be bothered to write here>. additionally this will give you only what's installed the uninstaller, not the application that runs them. Its likely what you want to do is basically unobtainable, as there are lots more applications installed then there are shortcuts ect

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I'll try the suggested methods.